# How filter_xss works in user_login_block?

Tags: 7

Does the form elements in [user_login_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_block/7) have the sanitized input elements using [filter_xss](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/filter_xss/7)?

## Update

This is the message that I've received:

Browsers are capable of displaying HTML and executing JavaScript. If the application does not escape special characters in the input/output and reflects user input as is back to the browser, an adversary may be able to launch a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack successfully.

Through XSS, an adversary may execute malicious files, install Trojans or steal the session token of a logged-in user.

The following URLs are vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS):

MYSITE.com/user/

Do I need to worry for this?

Comment: `filter_xss` is used on _output_, not input, so I guess the straight answer is "no". That said, all core code uses `filter_xss` when outputting markup received from the user, so you could also say "yes". It depends on your perspective

Comment: To address your edit: you need to find out what they're talking about, specifically. Drupal core doesn't have an XSS vulnerability, but of course you could have installed insecure custom or contrib modules, or an insecure theme, which _do_ have a vulnerability. No one but you (or someone else with access to the code and a test environment) can give you the information you need